# How to mock an instance of an interface?

Tags: testing, interfaces, mock

Having these interfaces

```
interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router {
  function getAmountsOut(uint256 amountIn, address[] memory path) external view returns (uint256[] memory amounts);
  function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint256 amountIn, uint256 amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint256 deadline) external returns (uint256[] memory amounts);
}

interface IUniswapV2Pair {
  function token0() external view returns (address);
  function token1() external view returns (address);
  function swap(uint256 amount0Out, uint256 amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external;
}
```

how could I mock on a test this:
`IERC20(_token).approve(router, _amount);`?

I've seen a couple libraries that can mock another contract, but couldn't find a solution to a contract instance from an interface

Answer (score 0):

got to actually build out the contract.

For a mock ERC20, the correct answer is that you can use OpenZeppelin:  https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC20

If you're like me though and want just one file and the bare minimum, I made one here: https://github.com/themandalore/charon/blob/main/contracts/mocks/MockERC20.sol

Comment: Right, but this implies on having these contracts locally, what if I just want to create an instance through an interface?

Comment: can't do that if you actually want to interact with it, there's no logic.

Comment: https://cryptomarketpool.com/interface-in-solidity-smart-contracts/#:~:text=An%20interface%20in%20Solidity%20behaves,order%20for%20it%20to%20operate.

are you sure? check out this article

Comment: yup I'm sure.  You usually just use an interface to interact with something you know is there.  So for example IERC20(tokenAddress).transfer(_to,_amount);  I don't need to know the specific contract logic of the tokenAddress, I just need to know it implements IERC20